# Calculating the total from identical tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Please advise on how I achieve the following transformation.

The input xml I have is of the format.

```
 <Employees>
     <Employee>
            <Name>Don</Name>
            <Salary>5000</Salary>
            <Expense>1000</Expense>
            <Expense>500</Expense>
            <Expense>300</Expense>
    </Employee>
     <Employee>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Salary>5000</Salary>
            <Expense>100</Expense>
            <Expense>400</Expense>
            <Tax>500</Tax>
            <Tax>200</Tax>
    </Employee>
```

And the output should be

```
<Employees>
     <Employee>
            <Name>Don</Name>
            <Salary>5000</Salary>
            <Expense>1800</Expense>
    </Employee>
     <Employee>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Salary>6000</Salary>
            <Expense>500</Expense>
            <Tax>700</Tax>
    </Employee>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You did not exactly make it clear that you tried writing XSLT code yourself. I'll show you how to process the `Expense` elements. Write

- a template that performs an identity transform to copy the whole input
- a template that matches the first `Expense` element, and let its content be the sum of all `Expense` children of its parent element
- a template that matches subsequent `Expense` elements and that does nothing

**XML Input**

Assuming the following, well-formed input (added `</Employees>` at the end):

```
<Employees>
     <Employee>
            <Name>Don</Name>
            <Salary>5000</Salary>
            <Expense>1000</Expense>
            <Expense>500</Expense>
            <Expense>300</Expense>
    </Employee>
     <Employee>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Salary>5000</Salary>
            <Expense>100</Expense>
            <Expense>400</Expense>
            <Tax>500</Tax>
            <Tax>200</Tax>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Expense[1]">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(../Expense)"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Expense"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
   <Employee>
      <Name>Don</Name>
      <Salary>5000</Salary>
      <Expense>1800</Expense>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Salary>5000</Salary>
      <Expense>500</Expense>
      <Tax>500</Tax>
      <Tax>200</Tax>
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

---

To apply this kind of processing to any child of `Employee`, use something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*/*[count(../*[name() = current()/name()]) &gt; 1 and not(preceding-sibling::*[name() = current()/name()] ) ] ">
         <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../*[name() = current()/name()])"/>
         </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*/*[preceding-sibling::*[name() = current()/name()]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
   <Employee>
      <Name>Don</Name>
      <Salary>5000</Salary>
      <Expense>1800</Expense>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Salary>5000</Salary>
      <Expense>500</Expense>
      <Tax>700</Tax>
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

and also reveals that your expected output is erroneous - John's salary should remain 5000 of course, not change to 6000.

Comment: Is there a difference between `Expense[not(preceding-sibling::Expense)]` and `Expense[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I would do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Employees">
    <Employees>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
            <Employee>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                <Salary>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(Salary)"/>
                </Salary>
                <Expense>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(Expense)"/>
                </Expense>
                <Tax>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(Tax)"/>
                </Tax>              
            </Employee>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Employees>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **result** (slightly different from the expected):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
   <Employee>
      <Name>Don</Name>
      <Salary>5000</Salary>
      <Expense>1800</Expense>
      <Tax>0</Tax>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Salary>5000</Salary>
      <Expense>500</Expense>
      <Tax>700</Tax>
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

---

If you prefer, you can output any or all of the summaries conditionally, e.g.

```
<xsl:if test="Tax">
    <Tax>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(Tax)"/>
    </Tax>  
</xsl:if>
```